# JavaScript Service Worker send message in background

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am using FCM and when I receive a notification in background I want to update some stuff on the page by sending a request to the we site. Even when the browser tab isn't in focus, but they are on the website just not actively on that tab

Is this possible?

I have tried this in my service worker.

```
clients.matchAll().then(function (clients){
        clients.forEach(function(client){
            client.postMessage({
                msg: "Hey I just got a message for you!",
                data: 'do-this'
            });
        });
    });
```

and this in my app

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {

            console.log(event);
        });
```

Is it even possible for the service worker to talk to the website in the background?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it, had to add { includeUncontrolled: true } into matchAll

Comment: Exactly what I needed! How you figured that out?